# Position flash object on tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, flash, tumblr

So I'm using [this flash fish code](http://abowman.com/google-modules/fish), and [this is my theme](http://clausetrophobia.tumblr.com). I'm trying to get the fish to stay in between the sidebar borders without moving outside. I've found that I can get the fish to stay in the sidebar if I move the sidebar using `left:600px` but then my sidebar overlaps my posts when I shrink the browser, and the theme displays differently on different screen resolutions. I'm new to all of this and I've tried so many things, I'm getting desperate.

Is there another way to get to fish to stay in the sidebar? Or just a way to keep using the left property without it overlapping the posts?

fish css

```css
#fish{
    position:fixed;
    padding-left:500px;
    width:100px;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;  
}
```

sidebar code

```css
#sb {
    background-image:url('');
    font-family:calibri;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:{color:sbtext};
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    left:600px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid {color:border};
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

posts code

```css
#stuffcontainer {
    margin-left:250px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:75px;
    text-align:justify;
    font-family:calibri;
    color:{color:text};
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding-left:200px;
}

#stuff {
    width:500px;
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:justify;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:90%;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
    color:{color:text};
    padding-bottom:15px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid {color:border};
    background-color:{color:bg};
}
```

fish code

```html
<div id="fish" style="position:fixed; left:120px;top:0px;"  class="main">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="outline:none;" data="http://cdn.abowman.com/widgets/fish/fish.swf?up_fishName=Fish&amp;up_fishColor3=D7EAF5&amp;up_backgroundColor=FFFFFF&amp;up_fishColor8=D7EAF5&amp;up_numFish=10&amp;up_fishColor10=D7EAF5&amp;up_backgroundImage=http://&amp;up_fishColor9=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor6=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor2=D7EAF5&amp;up_foodColor=BBBBBB&amp;up_fishColor5=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor7=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor1=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor4=D7EAF5&amp;"
  width="200" height="100%">
    <param name="movie" value=
    "http://cdn.abowman.com/widgets/fish/fish.swf?up_fishName=Fish&amp;up_fishColor3=D7EAF5&amp;up_backgroundColor=FFFFFF&amp;up_fishColor8=D7EAF5&amp;up_numFish=10&amp;up_fishColor10=D7EAF5&amp;up_backgroundImage=http://&amp;up_fishColor9=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor6=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor2=D7EAF5&amp;up_foodColor=BBBBBB&amp;up_fishColor5=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor7=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor1=D7EAF5&amp;up_fishColor4=D7EAF5&amp;" />
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="salign" value="tl" />
  </object>
```

update: I tried moving the fish code so that the code was in the same div as the sidebar. No luck.

Comment: Also my entire code can be found here http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KmAPyKuH

Answer (score 0):

Change the wmode parameter to transparent:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey not the answer you want I imagine but....

...I'm pretty sure the fish movement will be controlled by ActionScript inside the flash file. And unfortunately unless you have access to the source fla file (not just the swf file) you wont be able to manipulate the fish movement. I am guessing you don't as the file is hosted at http://cdn.abowman.com/

OK, I am going to start editing my answer.

The #fish container has the property

```
position:fixed,
```

this takes it out of the normal flow of the document.

If you want them to work responsively, I would create another div wrapper for the entire content, set it to an appropriate width. You can do

```
max-width:1200px; 
width:80%;
```

Then insert the #fish container inside this parent container that will wrap all page content.

If I get time I will try and create something for you.

Comment: Okay but like, i feel like the actual source file shouldn't matter? I don't really want to manipulate the fishes movement, I just want to flash object itself to stay in place. Is that really not possible? As you can see on my blog I actually go the fish to stay in place, but the sidebar is overlapping my posts. Isn't there a way to fix that?

Comment: OK, I am editing my answer, there is still some way to go though.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out a solution? I don't mean to bother you or anything.

Comment: That's great, that's the general idea I was going for. Could I get the code for it? The only thing is that it doesn't shrink when the window resizes, but I'm pretty sure that has to do with the margins anyway. I couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: I just checked it on different screen resolutions, is there a way to have the posts and sidebar centered in the middle of the theme on every resolution?

Comment: You might be able to get it looking more like that, but it is a trade off, as you have two elements that are fixed (they don't move even when scrolling). Using fixed positioning with a responsive layout is kind of contrary, so you would have to sacrifice something. I will post the code so far. I could of course work on it more, but we are getting to the stage where you would need to hire me as a freelancer, which is not really how SO works.

Comment: Alright, well thank you for the help anyway. I really appreciate it.